# Failed to emit precompiled header (opencv, xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, precompiled-headers, pch

My goal is to use **opencv** camera functions in react-native. Currently, I'm struggling to fix some errors.

My project contains many files: [image: file lists]

When I try to build the project, I got two errors. For me the second error is most important:

> Failed to emit precompiled header

[image: error messages]

(I have hidden my application name with black paint)

Below is what I've tried to solve those issues:

1. Clean project and rebuild.
2. Remove frameworks and add them again.
3. Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > click "Build" and check "Find Implicit Dependencies"
4. Check "platform :ios, 9.0" in podfile (Deployment Target in my project is 9.0)
5. Check whether Targets > Build Settings > Objective-C Bridging Header is set to 'OpenCVprofject_second-Bridging-Header.h', not pch file.

Unfortunately, I still get the same error messages.

Is there any other possible way to fix the precompiled header issue? If you need further information, please ask me...

Comment: Please include the relevant detail in the question, not as links. Actual content is much more helpful than pictures, that may not render on some screens.

Comment: Please tag questions with the actual version of the language yo are using, not multiple ones.

Comment: Sorry for u, but it's the first time to upload my question. I try to upload images, not links, but I don't know why the images are uploaded as links. I know it's uncomfortable to click links and see images.. Also, you can see which languages I use when you click the first link(image). Thanks for your commment.